CORS Issue while using Glean API chat
I am making API call to glean chat from react application and facing CORS issue.
glean-API docs: https://developers.glean.com/docs/client_api/chat_api/
endpoint: https://-be.glean.com/rest/api/v1/chat
I can see that there are no response headers. Can you all please tell how to overcome CORS Issue while using third party glean API
I am trying to hit endpoint: https://-be.glean.com/rest/api/v1/chat from react application and getting CORS error.
CORS issue needs to be resolved
